# Update a single file in the EAR file in a better way

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets

I have a `EAR` file with the following Structure

**app.ear**

```
  - APP-INF
    - lib
      // libraries (.jar) here
  - META-INF
    - MANIFEST.MF
    - weblogic-application.xml
  - module1.war
  - moduleJar.jar
  - module1.war
  - customlib.jar
```

Under `Module1.war`, I have updated the `Web.xml` and later I need to deploy the same `Ear` file, 
what is the better way to do this with out the `ANT` Script and Just from the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) software whit out extracting we can edit the files in `war,ear and jar`.

right click on `.ear->.7zip->select 'open archive'`

in side that select `'module1.war'->open`

like this you can reach to web.xml there select Edit on web.xml add or delete your lines.